# How to Capture Values from an Argument in HH:MM Format for a Shell Script

Tags: linux, bash, arguments

I'd like to build a Linux script with an argument in the format HH:MM.

An example invocation:

```
./my_script.sh 08:30
```

Within the script, I'd like to assign the hours and minutes to 2 vars, `HRS` and `MINS`.

So, for my example invocation `HRS` would be assigned the value 8, and `MINS` would be assigned the value 30.

I don't want an invocation format like:

```
./my_script.sh -hrs 08 -mins 30
```

How should I parse my input argument to get hours and minutes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very similar to this answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/918931/3421151

Using `IFS` with `read` works well since you can delimit the first argument by `:` which gives you an array of the hours and mins.

```
IFS=':' read -ra TIME <<< "$1"
HRS="${TIME[0]}"
MINS="${TIME[1]}"

echo "HRS: $HRS"
echo "MINS: $MINS"
```

Comment: Both of the above work well; I was also pleased to find that I could add a default value pretty easily with `HRS="${TIME[0]:-19}"`